# Deploy a Rails Application with Licencing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, licensing

were developing a ruby on rails application for a customer who wants the software to run on his server.
So, we want to have a mechanism that enables us to say that the customer may only use the software for a certain time.
Is there a way to "compile" the software that prevents the customer from tampering with the code?

Cheers,
Henning

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is far from trivial - ruby is script based, and there is no way to stop others from 'tampering' with your code.

There was a discussion about this on https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/60047, and here is one possible suggestion:

> One solution may be to compile a small app that takes an MD5, SHA, or
>   some other checksum of the ruby code and only executes it if it is in
>   an internal hash of allowed files. You could have user-based hashes of
>   allowed files based on who is logged in. Of course you will have to
>   rebuild this app every time you change the ruby code but that could be
>   automated. But a user could run the ruby code directly unless you
>   build in some dependency to the compiled app. If they can see the
>   source code, they can copy it, tamper with it, and run it.